# .htaccess redirect main domain?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect requests to `mydomain.tld/somepage.ext` to `mydomain.tld/mydomain/somepage.ext`? I have subdomains like `subdomain.mydomain.tld` that I don't want to be affected by this.

I can't seem to get it to work right. I'm trying this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /mysite/$1
```

But it isn't redirecting anything at all.

I also want to exclude one or two folders from this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysite/         # but I don't see why this line is needed when I've used [L] below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ignored_folder/
RewriteRule .* /mysite/$0 [QSA,L]
```

At least for now.